# What can a network owner see for google searches on an iPhone connected to their WiFi network?

Tags: encryption

Curious to see what a network (WiFi owner) can see for google searches on an iPhone connected to their network (a network that is protected by a password).

Comment: Is the iPhone yours, or is it theirs or is it managed in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TLS (HTTPS), then all they can see is that you're going to google.com; the search string and Google's responses are protected by TLS encryption.

When you click on a link in the search results, your computer may do a DNS lookup for that domain name, and then the TLS handshake as you connect to that site will leak the hostname (FQDN) of that site via the TLS SNI.

The IETF is working on ways to encrypt DNS lookup and fix the TLS SNI hostname leak, but those new privacy mechanisms have not been fully standardized and are still a ways from being deployed as of this writing (early 2019).

(I've edited this answer to incorporate good feedback from the comments below.)

Comment: And the second sentence should be something like, “But the data being transmitted to Google—such as the actual search string and response—will be encrypted.”

Comment: Does the default web browser / google search on an iPhone always use TLS?

Comment: If a link is clicked on, it is most likely possible to additionally see the domain name associated with the link if DNS is being sniffed.

Comment: @davidgo DNS sniffing isn't even necessary to see what site you're going to over a TLS connection, due to the TLS SNI. The IETF is working on ways to keep the SNI private, but for now, the TLS handshake leaks the hostname (FQDN) of the server you're connecting to.

Comment: @spiff interesting, and makes sense.